# Spring Boot 3.0.9 Feign Client Issue with Hystrix Command and Jackson Deserialization

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, deserialization, jackson-databind

I am upgrading my service from Spring Boot 2.3.5-RELEASE to 3.0.9. In this service, I am using a Feign client to make a call to another service. The relevant part of my Feign client interface looks like this:

```
@FeignClient(
    name = "store.search",
    url = "${services.store.url}"
)
public interface SearchClient extends SearchAPI<Content<?>> {}
```

The interface it is extending:

```
public interface SearchAPI <T extends Content> {

    @RequestMapping(method = GET, path = "/search/children")
    HystrixCommand<List<T>> searchChildren(
            @RequestParam("parentId") String parentId,
            @RequestParam("parentType") String parentType,
            @RequestParam("channels") List<String> channels,
            @RequestParam("query") String query) throws NotFoundException;
}
```

a service call is made as follows:

```
List<Content<?>> contents = searchClient.searchChildren(contentId, contentType, channels, query).execute();
```

However, this call is failing with a jakarta.servlet.ServletException, which is caused by a feign.codec.DecodeException. The root cause seems to be a com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException related to com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand. The exception indicates that Jackson is unable to construct an instance of HystrixCommand because it is an abstract class and no concrete types or custom deserializers are provided.

Here is the exception stack trace for reference:

```
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Request processing failed: feign.codec.DecodeException: Type definition error: [simple type, class com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1019)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:527)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:614)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1665)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at com.dodo.boot.profile.RequestProfileFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestProfileFilter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at com.dodo.commons.servlet.LoggingSetupFilter.doFilter(LoggingSetupFilter.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:527)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1570)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1381)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:484)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1543)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1303)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:563)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel$RequestDispatchable.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:1598)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:753)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:314)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectableChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectableChannelEndPoint.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:969)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.doRunJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:1194)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1149)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: feign.codec.DecodeException: Type definition error: [simple type, class com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand]
    at feign.InvocationContext.proceed(InvocationContext.java:40)
    at feign.ResponseHandler.decode(ResponseHandler.java:122)
    at feign.ResponseHandler.handleResponse(ResponseHandler.java:73)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:114)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:70)
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:96)
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignCachingInvocationHandlerFactory$1.proceed(FeignCachingInvocationHandlerFactory.java:66)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(CacheInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:351)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignCachingInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$create$1(FeignCachingInvocationHandlerFactory.java:53)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy204.searchChildren(Unknown Source)
    at com.dodo.cdp.topic.manager.service.ContentService.searchChildren(ContentService.java:63)
    at com.dodo.cdp.topic.manager.service.ContentService.searchOffers(ContentService.java:42)
    at com.dodo.cdp.topic.manager.controller.ContentController.searchOffers(ContentController.java:58)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:751)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(CacheInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.invokeOperation(CacheAspectSupport.java:366)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:420)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:345)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:751)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:703)
    at com.dodo.cdp.topic.manager.controller.ContentController$$SpringCGLIB$$0.searchOffers(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)
    ... 56 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:403)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:354)
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:103)
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.support.SpringDecoder.decode(SpringDecoder.java:75)
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.support.ResponseEntityDecoder.decode(ResponseEntityDecoder.java:61)
    at feign.optionals.OptionalDecoder.decode(OptionalDecoder.java:36)
    at feign.InvocationContext.proceed(InvocationContext.java:36)
    ... 96 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1915)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:414)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1360)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractDeserializer.java:274)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:2105)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1481)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:395)
    ... 102 common frames omitted

2024-01-12T16:14:36.408+01:00  WARN 95289 --- [tp1647560386-49] org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel     : handleException /content/search/offers/STATIC com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
```

I tried the suggestion on from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63924863/jackson-with-feign-cant-deserialized-springs-org-springframework-data-domain-s), adding on my application.yml

```
# Enabling Jackson autoconfiguration for Feign
feign:
  autoconfiguration:
    jackson:
      enabled: true
```

but I still get the same exception.

How can I resolve this Jackson deserialization issue with HystrixCommand in my Spring Boot 3.0.9 Feign client?